# Problem with syncronizing Vite and python scripts using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, vite

I know this is really specific but iam making a website using vite and trying to connect the python backend to my front end but i cant seem to get them to communicate, iam trying to learn flask so im using that could someone help me it would be much appreciated. As i said iam new to flask so this might be very obvious.

I tried by doing this on the html file:

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox">
<button onclick="sendData()">Send</button>
```

for the javascript i wrote this:

```
async function sendDataToPython(data) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData);
      // Process the response data as needed
    } else {
      console.error('Error:', response.status);
      // Handle error cases
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    // Handle error cases
  }
}
```

and for the python i wrote this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.json
    # Process the received data in your Python script
    response_data = {'message': 'Data received'}
    return jsonify(response_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I copied this from chatgpt as i have had no luck with finding people on discord to help me. If you need more info I will be happy to post it. Thanks in advance!

I expect for the input from a website to go to the python script and the the script run and return text as an output. It is a chat bot.